# JavaScript Date() returns Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, date

I am working on a website that will return the time since a certain date. But when I call `new Date()` with parameters the user has inputted, it returned "Invalid Date".

Here is the code I am using:
http://jsfiddle.net/8VkBu/ (the CSS looks a bit weird in the small window)

Why is it returned "Invalid Date", and how can I fix it?

Thanks,
Fjpackard.

Comment: can you pls tell me where exactly you are getting this error?

Comment: There is no error, the variable theDate is just equal to "Invalid Date"

Comment: Please don’t predeclare global variables if they’re used locally and logically local. It leads to confusing errors. `== true` has the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I update your [**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8VkBu/3/)

Please check..

your code should be following...

```
y = parseInt($("#year").val());
m = parseInt($("#month").val()) - 1;
d = parseInt($("#day").val());
h = parseInt($("#hour").val());
```

instead of

```
y = parseInt($("#years").val());
m = parseInt($("#months").val()) - 1;
d = parseInt($("#days").val());
h = parseInt($("#hours").val());
```

because your input id in html form is singular form

but in your jquery you use plural form

Such as in html you use **'year'** and in your jquery you use **'years'**

Comment: Wow! So obvious – sometimes when someone else looks at your code they see things that you just skip past because you assumed they were right. Thanks!